# Tons and tons of relay logs on a master

Tags: mysql, replication

I have a master that has 298 relay bin files as recent as today, going back well 298 days.

There is no relay-log definitions in the .cnf

and

```
mysql> show variables like '%relay%';
+---------------------------------+----------------+
| Variable_name                   | Value          |
+---------------------------------+----------------+
| innodb_overwrite_relay_log_info | OFF            |
| max_relay_log_size              | 0              |
| relay_log                       |                |
| relay_log_index                 |                |
| relay_log_info_file             | relay-log.info |
| relay_log_purge                 | ON             |
| relay_log_space_limit           | 0              |
+---------------------------------+----------------+
```

Reset slave clears them out, but then they just start getting regenerated.

Any idea what's causing this?  How to stop it?

**EDITS TO REQUESTS**

General critiques of the cnf are welcome but let's keep the OP topic in mind.

```
---- cnf request

[mysqld]
character_set_server = utf8

max_connections=200
max_user_connections=160
max_connect_errors=10000

userstat_running = 1

log_warnings
slow_query_log=1
slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time=2


innodb_file_per_table

innodb_open_files=2048

innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=1M

innodb_buffer_pool_size=512M

innodb_log_buffer_size=1M

innodb_log_file_size=128M

innodb_autoextend_increment=16


innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT


datadir=/var/lib/mysql/


tmpdir=/var/lib/mysql_ramdisk


server-id=2

log-bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin
log-bin-index = /var/log/mysql/mysql.index

key_buffer_size = 800M

preload_buffer_size = 256K

max_allowed_packet = 8M
table_cache = 512
sort_buffer_size = 8M
join_buffer_size = 8M

read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
thread_cache_size = 32
query_cache_size = 32M
query_cache_limit = 16M


myisam_sort_buffer_size = 2000M


tmp_table_size = 64M
max_heap_table_size = 64M

---- now for the cli requests

mysql> show slave status\G
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show master status;
+---------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| File                | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+---------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| awesome-bin.xxxxxxx | yyyyyyyy |              |                  |
+---------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)



---- version


mysql> select version();
+--------------------+
| version()          |
+--------------------+
| 5.1.47-rel11.1-log |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Please post MySQL version and my.cnf entries if possible.

Comment: `RESET SLAVE` on master with lot's of relay logs did it for me.

Answer (score 8):

If a Master has relay logs, then the Master must also be a Slave in the midst of some Replication topology (i.e., Master/Master, Daisy-Chained Replication)

What could cause relay logs to grow like this?

## BROKEN REPLICATION

MySQL Replication is broken when the IO Thread or SQL thread dies under these SCENARIOS:

- **SCENARIO #1** : When the IO Thread and SQL thread are off, one of two things happended

  - MySQL was started with [`skip-slave-start`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_skip-slave-start) enabled
  - Someone/something ran [`STOP SLAVE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stop-slave.html);
- **SCENARIO #2** : When the IO thread dies

  - nothing can pile up the relay logs
  - The SQL thread processes all SQL commands in the relay logs or until a SQL error occurs
- **SCENARIO #3** : When the SQL thread dies

  - SQL error occurred processing a SQL command
  - Running [`SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-slave-status.html) shows you the `Last_Errno` and `Last Error`
  - IO Thread continued collecting SQL commands from the Master, making relay logs grow

It is **SITUATION #3** that's the problem. *When the SQL thread dies due to a SQL error, there is no built-in mechanism in MySQL Replication that triggers the IO thread to disconnect*.

## RECOMMENDATION

The only decent way to control the growth of relay logs is to set the limit on it

```
[mysqld]
relay_log_space_limit=4G
```

Setting [**relay_log_space_limit**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_relay-log-space-limit) places a cap of 4G.

When a relay log is completely processed

- it is rotated out
- the SQL thread starts working on the next relay log
- the I/O thread starts loading SQL from the Master from the last place it left of from, as long as there is enough freespace on the disk

## EPILOGUE

If the Master used to be a Slave and it does not need to be anymore, simple disable it.

```
mysql -e"STOP SLAVE; CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='';"
rm -f /var/lib/mysql/master.info
```

If the Master is a Slave, go correct the SQL error.

I would suggest this if the SQL error is in the way:

```
STOP SLAVE;
SET GLOBAL sql_slave_skip_counter = 1;
START SLAVE SQL_THREAD;
```

then run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` every minute to see if the relay logs get processed and rotated.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your my.cnf, it's impossible to answer this question, but I would also suggest posting your SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G output - is it possible that your slave is actually incredibly far behind?  That would keep the relay logs around.  Is the SQL Slave thread running?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that my.cnf file is mis-configured and master binary logs are named as relay logs?

Or maybe your master has hard coded replication settings in my.cnf file, which are picked up at MySQL instance restart.

**EDIT:**
Did you mask the actual binlog filename in `show master status` output? I'm asking because the setting in my.cnf does not match the binlog name. If so, could you provide the actual filename, and the output of `show slave status` like Aaron mentioned? So far other than name mismatch for bin-log, nothing stands out in your my.cnf file.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the RESET SLAVE command. It will clean the relays logs and regenerates a new one. But, It will not use the new one. You can check by running later the FLUSH LOGS command, the server will not create a second relay log.

Comment: Can you expand your answer?  It is not clear what you mean.