# lot of relay log formation in mysql5.6

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.6

Reason for lot of small relay log file formation.
I Have setup a slave and it relay log rotates to soon and creates thousands of relay log file.whats the reason for more relay log formation.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible reasons seem to stick out,  ensure your server_id is different on both the master and the slave.  This is to be defined at startup in the cnf file.

Another option is you specified a very tiny max_binlog_size or max_relay_log_size, ensure the values are what you want and not off by an order of magnitude (eg. 512k instead of 512M)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one for the ages

I wrote an answer to a post on Jan 02, 2015 entitled [mysql replication master 5.5 slave 5.1 error on create database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87423/mysql-replication-master-5-5-slave-5-1-error-on-create-database/87438#87438). In that post, I learned from my boss about this strange situation when I was replicating from a MySQL 5.5 Master to a MySQL 5.6 Slave.

In short, I learned from some additional research that binary log events can change size and shape between major releases of MySQL.

This situation caused the following on the Slave:

- mysqld crashed
- mysqld_safe looped back and restarted mysqld
- `--skip-slave-start` was not configured
- mysqld crashed and restarted indefinitely
- relay logs piled up to the heavens
- I had to kill mysqld_safe to stop this craziness.

The solution for this scenario was to upgrade the Master to 5.6.

I also have a 3.5 year old post ([Tons and tons of relay logs on a master](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6983/tons-and-tons-of-relay-logs-on-a-master/8794#8794)) covering other situations.